# Auto Height of UICollectionView inside UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview

I want to create a cell that consist of title text, description text, and a collection view. So I tried to created a cell like this
[image: Custom Cell]

I added top, trailing, and leading to superview constraint for *title* and *description*. Then I also add top, bottom, trailing, and leading constraint to my `UICollectionView`.

For auto height my tableview cell, I override `viewWillAppear`

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 300
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

And in my custom cell class, I called `layoutIfNeeded()`

```
public func setRowWithData(model: DataModel) {
    // set your view here
    contentView.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

What I want is, all of cell in `collectionView` is showed and my `tableViewCell`'s height will adapt into it.

Is there any way to do it? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: https://github.com/IosPower/AppStoreLikeExampleSwift3

Comment: Would you like to add some introduction, @PiyushSinroja?

Comment: @SonicMaster Did you solve it?

Answer (score 1):

You can user content size observer of collection view to change the height of collection view according to its content at runtime.

To add the observer to your collection view you can use below method.

```
self.collectionView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "contentSize", options:   NSKeyValueObservingOptions.old.union(NSKeyValueObservingOptions.new), context: nil)
```

By using below callback method you can set the collection view height runtime.

```
override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
        self.collectionViewHeight.constant = self.collectionView.contentSize.height
}
```